# How to pipe exiftool into qpdf in bash?

Tags: bash, exiftool, qpdf

I am on Linux Mint 21.1.

I receive many documents which are either `.pdf`, `.png`, `.csv` or `.jpg` (rarely a `.xlsx`) from unknown parties. While my company email seems to have malware detection in the emails, I do not trust them completely. I want to purge all the meta-data, hidden java scripts in pdfs or macros.

For this task, I was advised to use `exiftool` and `qpdf`. While I am able to batch process files using exiftool using the command: `exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -all:all= *.*`, I am unable to do so with `qpdf`.

I am trying to run: `qpdf *.pdf --object-streams=disable --linearize --replace-input` but it does not execute and keeps telling me that it does not recognise the filename. What do I do?

It would be nice if I could pipe so that I can run `exiftool` and `qpdf` in one single command.

Comment: I do not believe that qpdf has the ability to batch edit files by itself.

Comment: With regards to your exiftool command, unless you are on a Mac and use the `XAtt*`/`MDItem*` file attributes, or on Windows using Alternate Data Streams, it would be quicker to use the [`-overwrite_original` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) instead of the [`-overwrite_original_in_place` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original_in_place), as the latter takes longer and doesn't give any advantage except in the cases I listed.